# What are these UML symbols?

Tags: uml

What are are the meanings of symbols marked 1,2 & 3 ?

[image]

Comment: If this is homework you should tag it as so.

Comment: No, not homework. I'm trying to implement design patterns and I'm not sure of some of the symbols. Diagram above taken from - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The first one is [aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Aggregation).
- The second one is a connector for the comment
- The thirs is a [dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Dependency).

Comment: The second connects with a comment, so it only explains something in the diagram.

Answer (score 3):

1) aggregation (special form of association)

2) this is simply the connector for the comment

3) generic dependency

Answer (score 1):

1) the open diamond means weak form of aggregation. This relationship denotes that
the aggregate class (the class with the white diamond touching it) is in some way the “whole”, and the other class in the relationship is somehow “part” of that whole.

2) Similar notation is used to represent an interface, but I don't think this is the case here, ergo - I don't know what it is.

3) The dashed arrow is a dependency relationship or ‘using’ relationship. This relationship simply means that ConcreteBuilder somehow depends upon Product.  This is very weak relationship and is not implemented with member variables at all.

Comment: Aggregation is a lifetime constrained form of association; not a weak form.